# HBase Export/Import: Unable to find output directory

Tags: import, hadoop, export, hbase

I am using HBase for my application and I am trying to export the data using `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export` as it was directed [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#export). The issue I am facing with the command is that once the command is executed, there are no errors while creating the export. But the specified output directoy does not appear at its place.The command I used was

```
$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export table_name db_dump/
```

Comment: Where have you looked for the export file? Your local file system? Or a path in hdfs? Have you tried specifying an absolute path?

Comment: Yes I have tried using absolute path......... and I was looking for the file at same place whose path I have given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution hence I am replying my own answer

You must have following two lines in hadoop-env.sh in conf directory of hadoop

```
export HBASE_HOME=/home/sitepulsedev/hbase/hbase-0.90.4
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HBASE_HOME/hbase-0.90.4.jar:$HBASE_HOME/conf:$HBASE_HOME/hbase-0.90.4-test.jar:$HBASE_HOME/lib/zookeeper-3.3.2.jar:$HBASE_HOME
```

save it and restart mapred by ./stop-mapred.sh and ./start-mapred.sh

now run in bin directory of hadoop

```
./hadoop  jar  ~/hbase/hbase-0.90.4/hbase-0.90.4.jar export your_table /export/your_table
```

Now you can verify the dump by hitting

```
./hadoop fs -ls /export
```

finally you need to copy the whole thing into your local file system for which run

```
./hadoop fs -copyToLocal /export/your_table ~/local_dump/your_table
```

here are the References that helped me out in [export/import](http://www.sethcall.com/blog/2010/04/10/how-to-export-and-import-an-hbase-table/) and in [hadoop shell commands](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/hdfs_shell.html)

Hope this one helps you out!!

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed the HBase export tool will create the backup in the HDFS, if you instead want the output to be written on your local FS you can use the file URI. In your example it would be something similar to:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export table_name file:///tmp/db_dump/
```

Related to your own answer, this would also avoid going through the HDFS. Just be very careful if your are running this is a cluster of servers, because each server will write the result files in their own local file systems.

This is true for HBase 0.94.6 at least.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous answer needs some modification:

- Platform: AWS EC2,
- OS: Amazon Linux
- Hbase Version: 0.96.1.1
- Hadoop Distribution: Cloudera CDH5.0.1
- MR engine: MRv1

To export data from Hbase Table to local filesystem:

```
sudo -u hdfs /usr/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export -Dmapred.job.tracker=local "table_name" "file:///backups/"
```

This command will dump data in HFile format with number of files equaling the number of regions of that table in Hbase.